# Ajax occasionally don't work. It does depends by the browser?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, datatables

I have an huge issue with my shopping cart system. The problem is when I select products and try to send through ajax to server side, products not always counted. I have to use ajax to collect all data because I'm using JQuery datatables plugin. 
List of products should looks like this:

[image: Correct view:]

[image: Incorrect view:]

Incorrect view is a screen from my windows firefox, correct view is from my chromium broswer on linux. It looks like there is some dependency on which browser running my webservice. I'm testing my webservice on server production and it works properly only on my chromium browser.

My buddy said there is in inappropriate data sent in Ajax code.

Here's my HTML template:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="panel-body">
<form method="post" action="{{ path('order') }}" id="orderList">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-default">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nazwa</th>
        <th>Kod</th>
        <th>Cena netto(zł)</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Cena brutto(zł)</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Ilość</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ product.productName }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.code }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ product.priceNetto }}</td>
        <td class="center hidden-xs">{{ product.priceBrutto }}</td>
        <td>

            <input type="number" class="spinner-input form-control" min="0" value="0" name="cart[{{ product.code }}]" />

        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
{%  if app.user != null %}
    <button id="getData" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary hidden-xs">Zamów</button>
{% else %}
    <p>Zaloguj się aby dokonać zamówienia</p>
{% endif %}
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#getData').click( function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();

    var paginator = $('#datatable-default').DataTable();

    var dat = paginator.$('input').serialize();
    console.log(dat);

    console.log(decodeURIComponent(dat));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('#orderList').attr('action'),
        data: {'orders': decodeURIComponent(dat)},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
});
});
```

And my server side code:

```
public function orderAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $totalPriceNetto = 0;
    $totalPriceBrutto = 0;

    $user = $this->getUser();
    $address = $user->getStreet();

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Products');

            $jsitems = $request->get('orders');
            $items = [];
            parse_str($jsitems, $items);

            $orderItems = [];
            foreach ($items['cart'] as $index=>$item)
            {
                if( $item != 0)
                {
                    $orderItems[$index] = $item;
                    $orders[$index] = $repository->findBy(['code' => $index]);
                    //$orders[$index][0]->setPriceBrutto(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $orders[$index][0]->getPriceBrutto())));
                    //$orders[$index][0]->setPriceNetto(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $orders[$index][0]->getPriceNetto())));
                    $orders[$index]['value'] = $item;
                }
            }


            $session->set('orders', $orders);
            $session->set('orderItems', $orderItems);

            foreach ($orders as $index=>$item)
            {
                $productObject = $item[0];
                $totalPriceNetto += floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $productObject->getPriceNetto()))) * (float)$item['value'];
                $totalPriceBrutto += floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $productObject->getPriceBrutto()))) * (float)$item['value'];
            }

            $totalPriceBrutto = round($totalPriceBrutto - ($totalPriceBrutto * $user->getPromo()/100), 2);


            $session->set('dd', $totalPriceNetto);
            $session->set('de', $totalPriceBrutto);

            return $this->render("/default/shop/makeOrder.html.twig", ['totalPriceNetto' => $totalPriceNetto, 'totalPriceBrutto' => $totalPriceBrutto, 'address' => $address]);
    }

    if($session->has('dd') && $session->has('de'))
    {
        $totalPriceBrutto = $session->get('de');
        $totalPriceNetto = $session->get('dd');

        $session->remove('dd');
        $session->remove('de');
    }
    return $this->render("/default/shop/makeOrder.html.twig", ['totalPriceNetto' => $totalPriceNetto, 'totalPriceBrutto' => $totalPriceBrutto, 'address' => $address]);
}
```

Comment: The problem I see is that you are using a submit button with ajax. Ajax is going to try to communicate with a server while your submit button is trying to submit the whole page.

Comment: After delete type from button, i still have same issue

Comment: deleting type makes it a submit by default. change it to type='button'

Comment: It's almost work perfect but when i change type to button it prevents me from redirect to `{{ path('order') }}` . When i type myself `/order` in url it works fine

Comment: I've also try to add `window.location = '/order';` when ajax succed, but there is no way to correct send data

Comment: Now i am confused. You are tying to submit upon a successful ajax call?  If that is the case, why are you bothering with ajax at all. Just submit the page.  Programically, $('form').submit() in your success might owrk

Comment: I am using datetables plugin so i need to collect all data(from pagination) in js. If i submit a form, there will be only one page(for example 50 of 1241 products)

Comment: unless you are running on a slow network, 1241 rows of data is not much.  I would get it all at once and let DataTables do client side paging. Once call, simple setup, etc

Comment: you can also collect your data en then call .submit() on the form but like Bindrid says don't use ajax and submit both. That does not make sense,